# I attempted to run script in Powershell - the script I copied was from Google Apps Script - Gmail, delete forever e-mails in trash with specific label

Tags: powershell, google-apps-script

And I got this response - please could you advise how I correct?

```
At line:1 char:25
+ function deleteForevers(userId) {
+                         ~
Missing ')' in function parameter list.
At line:1 char:31
+ function deleteForevers(userId) {
+                               ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
At line:2 char:3
+   var threads = GmailApp.search("in:spam");
+   ~~~
The 'var' keyword is not supported in this version of the language.
At line:4 char:21
+   for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
+                     ~
The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
At line:5 char:5
+     var msg = threads[i].getMessages()[0];
+     ~~~
The 'var' keyword is not supported in this version of the language.
At line:5 char:38
+     var msg = threads[i].getMessages()[0];
+                                      ~
An expression was expected after '('.
At line:6 char:26
+     if (msg.getPlainBody().match(/Do you want|Folder shared |wants to ...
+                          ~
An expression was expected after '('.
At line:6 char:34
+     if (msg.getPlainBody().match(/Do you want|Folder shared |wants to ...
+                                  ~
Missing ')' in method call.
At line:6 char:112
+ ... er shared |wants to say|Hi|Good day|Looking for|(no subject)/gi) !==  ...
+                                                                  ~
You must provide a value expression following the '/' operator.
At line:6 char:99
+ ... er shared |wants to say|Hi|Good day|Looking for|(no subject)/gi) !==  ...
+                                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
Not all parse errors were reported.  Correct the reported errors and try again.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndParenthesisInFunctionParameterList
```

I want to remove multiple junk emails from people trying to solicit some sort of sex site or with me etc.
I would also like to have a script that can run every other day - is this possible?

Please could you assist - I know I can just go into the gmail and click empty bin however I am getting 30 - 50 a day. Which is crazy.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Your code appears to be Java or C#, not PowerShell.

Comment: Oops I forgot to add the script I used- so here it is

Comment: function deleteForevers(userId) {
  var threads = GmailApp.search("in:Bin");

  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var msg = threads[i].getMessages()[0];
    if (msg.getPlainBody().match(/Do you want|Folder shared |wants to say|Hi|Good day|Looking for|(no subject)/gi) !== null){
        Gmail.Users.Messages.remove(userId, threads[i].getId().toString());
    }
  }
}
deleteForevers("[therorkies13@gmail.com]")

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code, don't use comments. My previous point still applies: this isn't PowerShell code.